# MediaWiki: creating a new user in private wiki

Tags: json, http, mediawiki

I've installed the MediaWiki engine hoping to create a private wiki with only two users, myself as an administrator to post information and another user to read it. Nobody warned me about this, but it turned out to be much complicated than I could imagined. I have to use jSON requests to perform actions like creating users and I have absolutely no experience in that. I managed to form a proper request, but now it tells me to use the POST request. I even found this site: http://requestmaker.com/ to simplify things, but still have no idea how exacly do I submit this command. Can I please have a newbie explanation on how I do this?

Comment: Have you tried Special:CreateAccount? it is pretty much straight forward...

Comment: Thank you!!! I had no clue this page exists! It's exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 2):

As DanielMK said, the Special:UserLogin page, linked from the top-right of the page in most MediaWiki skins, is the form to login and create accounts. Special:CreateAccount is the shortcut, useful in wikis where no "create account" link appears because only sysops have the permission to create accounts.

You can also use the ConfirmAccount extension to make a queue of account creation requests.